# How to exclude classes from polymorphism [JAVA]

Tags: java, methods, interface, polymorphism, superclass

I need that `Inteface` is implemented by different classes for its methods but also in order to use polymorphism on that supertype.
All the classes have the same characteristics and they must be children of a superclass or implement the same interface.

However one of the classes that implement `Interface` needs its methods but it should not be of type `Interface`.

Is there a way to exclude a class from polymorphism without cloning `Interface` and use it just for one class?

---

This is somewhere the interface I need it implements:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Interface
{
    Rapport makeRapport(Collection<Student> studs);

    default RapportType getType() 
    {
        return this.getClass().getAnnotation(Type.class).value();
    }    

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by exlcuding from polymorphism.  Can you include any code?

Comment: "_However one of the classes that implement `Interface` needs its methods but it should not be of type `Interface`._" This makes no sense - if it `implements` the `interface` then it _by definition_ _is a_; this is what inheritance means. Presumably you need the methods in order to call them - this makes it an `Interface`.

Comment: What do you mean "needs its methods"? Can't it just implement those methods without implementing Interface?

Comment: Interface has a default method and one abstract method. My subclasses need to be a Interface, also (but not only) because they use those methods.

One class of them is a bit different and it causes problems other classes don't cause, so I would like to implement that interface without considering that class an Interface.

Comment: [**PREFER COMPOSITION OVER INHERITANCE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance). This is why. So you don't end up with this. Whatever "this" is.